# A simple question on CLT in possible connection with Berry-Esseen thm

Tags: machine-learning, central-limit-theorem

I am curious about the contents while I read a note on machine learning. It could be obvious. So, please let me know if I am missing some fundamental things.

$X_1,X_2,...,X_n$ are from an i.i.d. distribution with mean $\mu$ and variance $\sigma<\infty$. Then,
by C.L.T, $s_n$ is approximately normal with mean $\mu$ and $\frac{\sigma}{\sqrt{n}}$, so that it has the density: $f_{s_n}(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{\frac{2\pi \sigma^2}{n}}}e^{-\frac{n}{2}\frac{(x-u)^2}{\sigma^2}}$.

What I cannot grasp is the following comment: **"This approximation is only valid for x within about $\frac{\sigma}{\sqrt{n}}$ of $\mu$"**. (FYI, this note is about large deviation.)

I also wondering how this statement is closely related to the **Berry-Esseen thm**.

Comment: Your statement about $P(S_n\leq x)$ is incorrect, and if you _correctly_ copied it word for word from a book, then shame on the authors.  That expression to the right of $\rightarrow$ is a _density_ function and is _not_ whatever $P(S_n \leq x)$ might be "converging" to. In any case, that $\rightarrow$ (which means "converges to" in standard mathematical notation) is shooting at a moving target because there is an $n$ on the right side which is "going to $\infty$". -1 until you fix the question suitably.

Comment: You are right I made a silly mistake. Thank you for letting me know. I will fix it.

Comment: The statement is _still_ incorrect. It is _not_ the case that the _density_ of $S_n$ is approximately what you claim it is.

Comment: @DilipSarwate Exactly... there are no limiting distributions for the sum, so approximating it based on a flawed interpretation of the CLT is a pretty dumb idea. There's no way that, whatever source provided this info, is credible.

Comment: Could you define $s_n$ in your question?

Answer (score 3):

There are several mistakes with the statement you give. I think a better resource for anyone interested in Machine Learning these days would be Tibshirani Hastie "Elements of Statistical Learning."

The correct statement of the CLT is that, given $X_1, X_2, \ldots, X_n \sim iid (\mu, \sigma^2)$,

$$\sqrt{n} \left(\bar{X} - \mu \right) \rightarrow_d \mathcal{N}(0, \sigma^2) $$

(note that several of these "assumptions" can be relaxed, ref Lindeberg Feller CLT)

A consequence is that the distribution of the sample *mean* can be approximated using a $\mathcal{N}(\bar{X}, \sigma^2/n)$ distribution. The *cumulative sum* $S_n$ is given by $n \bar{X}$ which would have an approximating distribution of $\mathcal{N}(n\mu, n\sigma^2)$ (recall $\mbox{Var}(aX) = a^2 \mbox{Var}(X)$).

The last problem with your statement is that you confuse the probability *density* function for a normal curve with a cumulative DF. The $Pr(S_n <x)$ would be best approximated with $Pr(S_n < x) \approx \Phi(\frac{x - n\mu}{\sqrt{n \sigma^2}})$ (not $\phi$)... but that seems like a silly thing to approximate when the sample mean is so much more regularly behaved... i.e. it actually converges to something.

The *range* in which you refer to the accuracy of the approximation is complete bunk. The CLT is certainly based on a Taylor series expansion... but making a rule of thumb about it is useless. More $n$ implies better approximating distribution, that's all we can say about it.

From what I gather, Barry-Essen has nothing to do with any of this.

All in all, please disregard the note.

Comment: Thank you for the comments. I guess the note was hiding some procedures on their argument and I hastily adopt it line by line. I will take more care of the contents.